# ion-router-outlet in other page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router, router-outlet

I have an ionic angular project, and I have the ion-router-outlet in the app.component.html that redirect to the teacher page

route in app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
     path: '',
     redirectTo: 'teacher',
     pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
     path: 'login',
     component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
     path: 'teacher',
     loadChildren: () => import('./pages/teacher/teacher.module').then(m => m.TeacherPageModule)
  },
  {
     path: 'admin',
     loadChildren: () => import('./pages/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminPageModule)
  }
];
```

and in the teacher page, I redirect to the classes page

teacher-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
     path: '',
     redirectTo: 'classes',
  },
  {
     path: 'classes',
     component: ClassesComponent
  }

];
```

and I want to show the classes page in the teacher page

teacher.page.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>teacher</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet> //<< classes page in here
</ion-content>
```

but it shows just content of classes page and doesn't execute the teacher page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems me you haven't declared the 'loadChildren' route to the 'classes' in the Route. Something like:

```
  {
     path: 'classes',
     loadChildren: () => import('./pages/classes/classes.module').then(m => m.ClassesPageModule)
  }
```

> Note: this component should only be used with Angular projects. For vanilla or Stencil JavaScript projects, use `ion-router` and `ion-route`.